# Select rows from table where value in column appears ones

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table with three fields as shown below:

Table : `Testing`

```
create table testing
(
   colnum varchar(10),
   coldate date,
   colid int
);
```

Insertion :

```
insert into testing values('111','2015-01-01',1);
insert into testing values('111','2015-01-02',1);
insert into testing values('111','2015-01-03',1);
insert into testing values('111','2015-01-04',1);
insert into testing values('111','2015-01-05',1);
insert into testing values('222','2015-01-01',1);
insert into testing values('333','2015-01-01',1);
```

Index creation:

```
create clustered index id_idx on testing(colid);
create nonclustered index date_nidx on testing(coldate);
create nonclustered index num_nidx on testing(colnum);
```

**Note**: Now I want to display the records who is **only in** specific date and specific ID not the other date.

For example: I want to display the records who is **ONLY IN** specified date and ID but not the other dates.

Given Date: `2015-01-01`
Given ID  : `1`

For which I have written following query:

```
select * from testing
where coldate in ('2015-01-01')
      and coldid = 1
      and colnum not in(select colnum from testing where coldid = 1 and
                        coldate in('2015-01-02','2015-01-03','2015-01-04'
                             '2015-01-05');
```

Result:

```
colnum   coldate     colid
--------------------------
222     2015-01-01    1
333     2015-01-01    1
```

**Explaination**: The query shows two records because both records have only in specific date and id **But** the record `111` not shown because that also belongs to other dates as you can see in the above table.

The above query works fine for me **But** taking more time for execution for billions of records.

Comment: as per your conditions, `111` should also be returned?

Comment: Are there any index in your table?

Comment: Kindly post the create index script.

Comment: Try this instead: `create nonclustered index nci_testing on testing (colid, coldate) include(colnum)`

Comment: Yes, there'll be an effect on `INSERT` and `DELETE`. But you can now delete the other index you had created.

Comment: But please do extensive testing first.

Comment: FYI: Indexes always add *some* overhead to modification statements (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE), but the overhead is very small, while the performance gain (when the index applies) is usually *very* large.  So usually indexes are well worth it, as long as they are actually used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT colnum, coldate,colid 
FROM 
( 
 select *,COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY colnum) as cnt 
from (SELECT DISTINCT colnum, coldate,colid from testing ) t
) q
where  q.cnt=1 and q.coldate in ('2015-01-01') and q.colid = 1
```

fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/650c0/4

Comment: This will not match the expected result as  '111','2015-01-01',1 will be in the output

Comment: don't think this will fix it.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense and that is the fastest way to my knowledge.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi, Just insert this `insert into testing values('333','2015-01-01',1);` for 3 times and run your script. It has to show in the result because it is only in the same date but multiple times but it has to be shown in the result.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi, There is still error in result. If I insert this `insert into testing values('333','2015-01-08',8);` then `333` should not appear in the result. Please check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I have made some assumptions on the basis of the result in your example.

- you want specific date and not the other date
- you want all the colid(s) (as per your example)

Can you please check if this is the expected result?

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM   testing t 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
                  FROM   testing 
                  WHERE  coldate <> '2015-01-01') x 
              ON x.colnum = t.colnum 
WHERE  x.colnum IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this following.you will get the record 111 also.

select * from testing

where coldate = '2015-01-01'

and colid = 1;

and for the execution time ,you just create a index on that table.so it will increase your execution performance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It will be interesting to compare the speed to this:

```
SELECT colnum,colid, min(coldate) as coldate
FROM testing 
GROUP BY colnum,colid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT coldate) = 1 
  AND colid = 1
  AND min(coldate) = '2015-01-01'
```

Comment: Just insert this `insert into testing values('333','2015-01-01',1);` for 3 times and run your script. It has to show in the result because it is only in the same date but multiple times but it has to be shown in the result

Comment: I have updated the query to count distinct number of dates